# Swift 3 function to POST data and I have an error when I receive JSon answer from my server

Tags: php, ios, json, swift3

I have a function in Swift 3 to POST data to a PHP server. The PHP server send a JSon answer to iOS and I have an error.

This is my function :

```
func sendRequestPost(urlString: String, dataToPost: String, completion: @escaping (_ dictionary: NSDictionary?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        let postString = dataToPost

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // Check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // Check for http(s) errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                // make error here and then
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

            print("responseString : \(responseString)!")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("DispatchQueue.main.async")
                do {
                    print("enter do")
                    let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any] as NSDictionary

                    print("jsonDictionary")
                    print(jsonDictionary)

                    completion(jsonDictionary, nil)
                } catch {

                    print("CATCH ERROR !")
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

For example I call my function like that :

```
            let url = "https://mywebsite.com/signup/ios/signup.php"
            let postData = "username=\(txtUsername.text!)&password=\(txtPassword.text!)&confirmPassword=\(txtConfirmPassword.text!)&email=\(txtEmail.text!)&firstname=\(txtFirstname.text!)&lastname=\(txtLastname.text!)"

            sendRequestPost(urlString: url, dataToPost: postData) {
                dictionary, error in

                print("---directory---")
                print(dictionary)
                print("---error---")
                print(error)
                print("==========")
```

This is what I see in the console :

responseString : "{\"exception\":false,\"success\":false,\"status\":-9,\"message\":\"This username already exist !\",\"confirmMessage\":\"null\",\"html\":\"null\",\"data\":\"boblongueuil\"}"!
DispatchQueue.main.async
---ENTER DO :
CATCH ERROR !
---directory---
nil
---error---

## Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})

So how can I return the JSon string after call this function to see a registration is OK or registration have a problem (in this case the username already exist in database). I change answer from my PHP server to an array.

Comment: With removing the escape characters which Optional added, your `responseString` is enclosed in double-quotes. It's a JSON string, which contains a text representation of JSON object -- double-encoded.  I recommend you to **re-configure your PHP server**, as double-encoded JSON is inefficient for both server and client, which consumes more time and space.

Comment: Now PHP server return array result is : responseString : "{\"exception\":false,\"success\":false,\"status\":-9,\"message\":\"This username already exist !\",\"confirmMessage\":\"null\",\"html\":\"null\",\"data\":\"boblongueuil\"}"!
DispatchQueue.main.async
---ENTER DO :
CATCH ERROR !
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}) Why let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary
line have an error ??

Comment: If you get that output `responseString : "{...` from the line `print("responseString : \(responseString)!")`, (Isn't it `print("responseString : \(responseString!)!")` ? But how you print it is irrelevant)  it still contains double-quotes at both ends. Fix the php side, or else you cannot get the right JSON to work with your code.

Comment: This is exactly what my PHP server return : $result = array('exception' => false, 'success' => false, 'status' => -10, 'message' => 'This email address already exist in our system !', 'confirmMessage' => 'null', 'html' => 'null', 'data' => $email);

Comment: Tell the PHP server side engineer, that returning double-encoded JSON is a bad design or a bug and indicating poor skills of the implementor, which should be fixed.